# out parameters in object initializer during anonymous instantiation

Tags: c#, out, object-initializers

If I have an object containing a public int property (public accessors), how can I parse a string to int when initializing this property at instantiation ?

```
// Given initialized DataTable table;
// Given public int IntProperty {get; set;} in public class MyObject    
table.Rows.Select(row => new MyObject 
{
   int.TryParse(row["stringValue"], IntProperty), // MyObject.IntProperty is unknown here
   IntProperty = int.TryParse(row["stringValue"], ... ) // IntProperty is known but what about the out int result argument of Int32.TryParse ?
});
```

EDIT : I could do this but want to know if there is a way to do it directly inside object initializer :

```
table.Rows.Select(row => {
    int.TryParse(row["stringValue"], out int intProperty);
    return new MyObject 
    {
       IntProperty = intProperty;
    }
});
```

Comment: Not everything has to be squeezed into an object initializer. A regular method would have no trouble calling `Int.TryParse` first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly agree Jeroen Mostert. Instead of "squeezing everything into an object-initializer", make your code readable and easy to unserstand. Than it´ll probably compile without problems:

```
var result = new List<MyObject>();
foreach(var row in table.Rows)
{
    var instance = new MyObject();
    int value;
    if(int.TryParse(row["stringValue"], out value)
        instance.IntProperty = value;
    result.Add(instance);
}
```

In C#7 you can also simplify this a bit to the following:

```
var instance = new MyObject();
if(int.TryParse(row["stringValue"], out int value)
    instance.IntProperty = value;
result.Add(instance);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure, your stringvalue will always be parseable to int you can use `int.Parse()`

Otherwise, you will also have to handle a failed parsing. You can do like this:

- define the `out` parameter in the outer scope
- use it in an assignment in case of successful parsing

**WARNING** This will fail, if you traverse your list in parallel!

```
    List<string> list = new List<string>{"1", "2", "3"}; 
    int i = 0;
    var ilist = list.Select(x => new MyObject {
        IntProperty = int.TryParse(x, out i) ? i : 0
    });
```

**EDIT** With inline declarations from VS2107 you can even do it without the variable from the outer scope

```
    List<string> list = new List<string>{"1", "2", "3"}; 
    var ilist = list.Select(x => new MyObject {
        IntProperty = int.TryParse(x, out int i) ? i : 0
    });
```

Comment: Nice, with c#7, the out variable means (to me) that this is no longer "squeezing everything in"

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `out` variable to assign it back to `IntProperty`, so I reckon there is no way to do it one statement inside of object initializer.

Either use `int.Parse` or wrap the call to `int.TryParse` in another utility method you create that returns in instead of bool and call it instead.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to use out argument with object initializer.

You could just use `Int.Parse` if you expect this row to always contain an integer, and then catch an exception. I would say that this the correct way to do this.

```
try
{
    table.Rows.Select(row => new MyObject 
    {
       IntProperty = int.Parse(row["stringValue"]) 
    });
catch (FormatException)
{
    // handle format exception    
}
```

If you still want to use `Int.TryParse`, then you would need to use body statement:

```
table.Rows.Select(row => {
    bool parseResult = int.TryParse(row["stringValue"], out int x); 
    // TODO: handle parseResult! do not ignore it     
    return new MyObject 
    {
        IntProperty = x
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it in the way you are trying to do this, you need an intermediate variable to store the out value:

```
// Given initialized DataTable table;
// Given public int IntProperty {get; set;} in public class MyObject    
table.Rows.Select((row) => 
{
    if(int.TryParse(row["stringValue"], out int intValue)){
        return new MyObject 
        {
            IntProperty = intValue
        };
    }
    else {
        //do error handling
    }
});
```